# refreshing a div with the <script> tag in it

Tags: javascript, php, html, refresh, reload

with this code , i want to make the div 'refresh' reloads every 10 sec :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function(){
            $('#refresh').empty();
            $('#refresh').load('index.php?_=' +Math.random()+' #refresh').fadeIn("slow");
        }, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
    </script>
```

the code works with `<ifram>` tag in the div , as an exemple :

```
<div id="refresh" align="center" ><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/wEhniGlFDtA?feature=player_detailpage" ></iframe></div>
```

but when i want to put a `<script>` in the div , the `<script .... ></script>` after the reload disappears , example :

```
<div id="refresh" align="center" ><script language="javascript" src=" #some_ads_src "></script></div>
```

can someone please tell me where's the probleme ? (srry for my english , new here )

Comment: the goal here is to make a div with an ads in it and make it refresh every 60 sec and the ads is in the <script .. ></script> form ,

Comment: `1.` If a `<script>` tag existed before it disappears, don't worry! The _JavaScript_ which it contained was still loaded into memory and will continue to be there unless something overwrites it. `2.` If the page disappears when you include a `<script>` **after** the page has loaded, check if the script uses `document.write`. Any call to `document.write` when the document is not "open" (i.e. after it has loaded) will call `document.open`. This will clear the _DOM Tree_ as it basically sets the _HTML_ to an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line removes all child nodes from `#refresh`, *including embedded script tags*:

```
$('#refresh').empty();
```

...then this line loads data from the server and places the returned HTML into `#refresh`:

```
$('#refresh').load('...').fadeIn("slow");
```

The obvious solution is that `#refresh` should be empty because its content will be loaded by AJAX. The internal `script` tag should be moved somewhere else.